# Mitsubishi Colt trip computer mode change?

Tags: audio, mitsubishi, electronics, colt

I have a Mitsubishi Colt (2004 model, 5-door) where I've replaced the factory head unit / radio.

Unfortunately this meant I lost the capability of switching the trip computer modes (instant/average fuel consumption, expected range, etc.), since the mode switching button was embedded in the head unit.

[image: colt factory radio]

Inside the dashboard there are 2 connectors, one for the head unit main functions (power, speakers, etc.) and another for the trip computer (to display the station, CD track number, etc.).

After switching the factory head unit the trip computer connector was left unused, but I suppose it has some control wires that change the mode when shorted.

It's a 14-connector plug, but it only has 6 wires running into it.

[image: colt LCD plug]

Where can I find the pinout for this connector? 
I was thinking of attaching a pushbutton switch to change the mode. Would it work?

Comment: This is a great question!

Answer (score 2):

I checked this out in a 2012 Colt. There was the same connector but only with 3 pins connected. Green, purple and pink.

I found out The Sony XAV head units have integrated steeringwheel control for japanese cars. I conencted green and purple to tip and ground and it started working directly.

I measured the old radio what was happening on the pink cable, this has 12V on it but when you press the mode button on the radio it goes to ground.

Just tried what happens when a tap ground with the pink wire-> The trip computer jumps to the next mode.

So a simple push button with pink and ground will solve this requirement. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Connect the factory head unit to the harness.

While pressing the button measure each wire for changes. You should see a noticeable fluctuation that matches the button pushing.

Tap into the cable(s) and create your own little harness with connector. Get a standard connector at the local auto parts store.

Connect the button of your choice to the connector. Bonus point if you can make it look from the factory. :)

**What if this doesn't work?**

It could be that the button is part of a control module that is linked to the display. In that case, you would have to perform surgery on the radio unit and remove the module. Then it would be a matter of placing it in a convenient but not visible area of the dash.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a plan. Unfortunately I have zero electronics experience and tools. Measuring the voltage in each wire would only identify the positive one, right? How would I determine the ground pin? More importantly, how to measure the voltage without stripping the wires?

Comment: To measure: Use the multimeter lead (pointy and thin) and press it into the back of the connector. It will make contact with the metal connector inside the plastic housing. The ground pin is usually black. Or black with grey stripes. If this sounds like too much trouble just pull the button out of the housing like I said above. :D

Comment: Couldn't I just short the pins two at a time until it performed the desired action? Should I? :D

Comment: I dont recommend it but its your car. A quick short with a paperclip should not hurt anything.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.mitsubishi-forums.com/74-2003-colt/11357-electronic-hidden-menu-colt-cz3.html#/topics/11357?page=2

No need for any of these. According to the above article you can change the mode by pressing the A button while turning the key to On.